# SendMessage simulated action is working when mouse is being moved only. Is there a way to solve that?

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I'm working on a 'drag' action in game'ss window. I want to mouse_down in a one place and then mouse_up another one.

Here's the c# code:

```
uint Iparm = makeDWord((ushort)x, (ushort)y);
IntPtr xd = new IntPtr(Iparm);
uint Iparm2 = makeDWord((ushort)x2, (ushort)y2);
IntPtr xd2 = new IntPtr(Iparm2);

SendMessage(p, (uint)0x201, (IntPtr)0x1, xd); // down button (start x,y)
SendMessage(p, (uint)0x202, (IntPtr)0x0, xd2); // up button (final x,y)
```

I have connected that code with a button (lets say button named START) in a c# form. When I push START and keep on moving my mouse, it works perfectly. But when I just push START and wait for the action (without moving the cursor on the screen), nothing happens. I've checked game's window with spy++ while pushing button in my form, and there's no difference between two ways of pushing that button (moving/not moving cursor).

I've forgotten to add that while moving cursor, action takes place even though window is minimized (what is very cool)

What's causing my problem ? : P

**edit:**

```
WM_MOUSEDOWN = 0x201;
WM_MOUSEUP = 0x202;
```

That code is placed in a function, p is windows handle, button START executes that function.

As I said before, the code works just fine while I'm moving cursor

Comment: Pardon me for not having all the Windows messages memorized. What are 0x201 and 0x202? Are those WM_MOUSEDOWN and WM_MOUSEUP? Also, where is this code in your program? Is it in the button handler for your start button? A little more context will help.

Comment: edited the info You needed :P

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `SendMessage` with a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message in between the down and up.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead.

Comment: can i use it to a minimized window? to a specified window?